# Как распараллелить в python цикл с двумя вложенными?

Tags: python, многопоточность, циклы

```
    for i in range(2,10):
        for j in range(1,500):
           for k in range(1,15):
              print(i,j,k)
```

update:

```
    for i in range(2,10):
    for j in range(1,500):
    for k in range(1,15):
        digits = datasets.load_digits()
        np.putmask(digits.data, digits.data == 1, 0)
        np.putmask(digits.data, digits.data == 2, 0)
        np.putmask(digits.data, digits.data == 13, 12)
        X_digits = digits.data
        Y_digits = digits.target
        split = int( len( X_digits ) *(0.75 + k*0.01))
        X_train = X_digits[:split]
        Y_train = Y_digits[:split]
        X_test = X_digits[split:]
        Y_test = Y_digits[split:]
        knn = KNeighborsClassifier( n_neighbors = 4, n_jobs= -1, p=2)
        bagging = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=knn, n_estimators=i, n_jobs=-1, random_state = j)
        bagging.fit(X_train,Y_train)
        if bagging.score(X_test, Y_test)> 0.97:
            print(bagging.score(X_test, Y_test),i,j,k)
```

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос по-другому... Опишите что вы хотите сделать. Распараллеливать вывод на печать - задача малополезная...

Comment: Если хотите ускорить код, то это можно сделать, например, так: `from itertools import product` `for a, b, c in product(range(2, 10), range(1, 500), range(1, 15)):` `print(a, b, c)`

Comment: по сути хочу ускорить поиск лучших параметров, это задачка с распознаванием цифр

Comment: реализация игрушечная, без использования GridSearch и т.д. - просто интересно на этом уровне понять как сегодня распараллеливается подобный кейс

Comment: а я как раз хотел предложить вам использовать GridSearchCV... ;-)

Comment: Кстати цикл для разных random_state - совершенно пустая трата времени

Comment: Спасибо, Максим. Исследую multithreading вобщем, а то взял i9 (16 потоков). Ждать не люблю)

Comment: поздравляю! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Если не надо получать никаких данных обратно, то достаточно просто отдать функции отдельным процессам. сначала засунем содержимое внешней петли в функцию:

```
def run_one(i):
    for j in range(1, 500):
        for k in range(1, 15):
            print(i, j, k)

for i in range(2, 10):
    run_one(i)
```

Это абсолютно эквивалентно оригинальному коду.

Теперь используем multiprocessing.Process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def run_one(i):
    for j in range(1, 500):
        for k in range(1, 15):
            print(i, j, k)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(2, 10):
        Process(target=run_one, args=[i]).start()
```

Запуск процессов находится под блоком main, иначе он будет ругаться.

Если нужно получать переменные обратно из процессов, то хороший вариант работать с concurrent.futures.

```
from concurrent import futures


def run_one(i):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(1, 500):
        for k in range(1, 15):
            sum += i*j*k

    return f"Sum for i = {i}", sum

if __name__ == "__main__":


    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

        todo = []

        for i in range(2, 10):
            future = executor.submit(run_one, i)
            todo.append( future )

        for future in futures.as_completed(todo):
            print(future.result())
```

Вывод:

```
('Sum for i = 2', 26197500)
('Sum for i = 5', 65493750)
('Sum for i = 3', 39296250)
('Sum for i = 4', 52395000)
('Sum for i = 6', 78592500)
('Sum for i = 7', 91691250)
('Sum for i = 8', 104790000)
('Sum for i = 9', 117888750)
```